# How to drop file onto WPF Image control inside listbox

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

I have a WPF window with this xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Border" x:Key="BorderStyle">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="Image" x:Key="ImageStyle">
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="75"/>
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="75"/>
            <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="True"/>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <GroupBox>
            <Grid>
                <ListBox x:Name="listbox">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                                <Border Style="{StaticResource BorderStyle}">
                                    <Image Style="{StaticResource ImageStyle}" Drop="ThisDrop"/>
                                </Border>
                                <Border Style="{StaticResource BorderStyle}">
                                    <Image Style="{StaticResource ImageStyle}" Drop="ThatDrop"/>
                                </Border>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
            </Grid>
        </GroupBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And this code behind:

```
using System.Linq;

namespace WpfApplication2
{
    public partial class MainWindow
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            listbox.ItemsSource = Enumerable.Range(1, 3);
        }

        private void ThisDrop(object sender, System.Windows.DragEventArgs e)
        {
            // do something
        }

        private void ThatDrop(object sender, System.Windows.DragEventArgs e)
        {
            // do something else
        }
    }
}
```

I'm having a hard time getting those drop events to fire when I drag and drop a file on the image controls from windows explorer.

Project:
https://github.com/ronnieoverby/WpfApplication2

Comment: Did you set AllowDrop to true on the Image element?

Comment: I've set allowdrop=true on every element in the heirarchy, just trying to get this to work.

Comment: @RonnieOverby You can't put two `Border` elements inside the `DataTemplate` (The property "VisualTree" can only be set once). Check your XAML.

Comment: I didn't. The structure was wrong. Updated.

Comment: I've updated the question with the actual xaml and c# and github repo to demonstrate the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```xml
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <!-- Using a StackPanel here since DataTemplate can't contain more than one element-->
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image AllowDrop="True" Drop="ImageDrop1"/>
                <Image AllowDrop="True" Drop="ImageDrop2"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

And here are the `Drop` event handlers

```cs
private void ImageDrop1(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Dropped onto Image 1");
    e.Handled = true;
}

private void ImageDrop2(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Dropped onto Image 2");
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the problem was that the image control source hadn't been set yet.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a basic Drag and Drop operation:

```
private void Image_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
    {
        // Signal the user they can copy files here
        e.Effects = DragDropEffects.Copy;
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}

private void Image_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    string[] fileList = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop) as string[];

    if (fileList != null)
    {
        foreach (string file in fileList)
        {
            // Do stuff
        }

        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

I usually implement DragOver and have DragEnter simply call DragOver because I find sometimes if the DragEnter event doesn't always fire.  But that was using Windows Forms, may not be necessary for WPF.

Setting the DragDropEffects does two things.  It changes the icon so the user has a visual cue of what will happen (copy, move, etc.).  It also tells the caller (the application that started the drag drop) what happened so it knows how to react.  For example, for a move operation it might delete the original files.

You use e.AllowedEffects to see what effects the caller application supports.  For example, it might not support moving, only copying.  It's up to the developers on both ends to make sure their application meets the convention of what Link, Move, and Copy mean.  As far as the API is concerned it only affects the icon shown to the user.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should to make an AttachedProperty that recive an ICommand, then (in the view model) inside this command to put the code; inside the attached property subscribe to the OnDrag event and execute the ICommand, and then in the view (the Image) to bind the attached property to the command.

Comment: Why would I want to do that? Sounds like over engineering to me and it doesn't do anything to address the problem I was having.

Comment: Sorry for delay. I tell this because i had used this before. I could suply the code for to do this if you still wants.

Comment: I'm not real concerned with MVVM principles for this project and I solved my problem anyway. See my answer.